# how to transparent a nvabar in HTML for desktop and same nave bar show on toggle in mobile screen.?

Tags: html, css, frontend, custom-pages

hello everyone **how to transparent a **nvabar** in **HTML** for desktop and same navebar show on toggle in mobile screen.?** by using media query.

Comment: So want some background for mobile devices, and transparent for desktop ?

Comment: A brand always display on right but on left Navbar display only on mobile screen.

Answer (score 0):

In HTML:

```
<div class="nav">
// opened navbar codes here
</div>

<div class="toggled">
// toggled navbar codes here
</div>
```

In CSS:

```
.toogle{
display:none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px){
.toogle{
display:block;
}

.nav{
display:none;
}
}
```